# JSON only works for one url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

So I have 2 urls to json files.
One is structured:

```
{
   "playerStatSummaries": [
      {
         "aggregatedStats": {
            "averageObjectivePlayerScore": 556
         },
         "wins": 0
      },
```

the other is structured:

```
{
   "matches": [
      {
         "champion": 254,
      },
```

So for the first one I can get the int wins by using

```
json.playerStatSummaries[0].wins;
```

Though for the second array when I try to get the champion it ends up with nothing returned.

```
json.matches[0].champion
```

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Can you maybe demonstrate the issue in a JSFiddle?

Comment: Apparently, your JSON is not exactly what you think it is or there is an error in it because the code looks fine so like the data is not exactly what you think it is.  Note - both pieces of Javascript you show us are incomplete (missing a closing of the array and a closing of the top level object).  I'd suggest you do a `console.log()` on both pieces of data in your app to see exactly what they really are.

Comment: I think there are some `syntax error` inside the 2th JSON. Test it here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Can you please try printing 'json.matches'. What you can see in your browser console?

Comment: can you post your JSON in full ? @armaiz adenwala